# A mandatory label user control in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, label

Ok - I just need some ideas here. The scenario is - There are a lot of fields in my windows form which are mandatory to be entered by the user. One of them might be "Name". So for this, I have a label `lblName` with text `Name`, another label `lblMandatory` with text `*` colored in red which signifies it is mandatory. So that means I have two labels for a field `Name`, and similarly I have more than 20 fields in my form. I was just thinking of creating a custom label - something called `MandatoryLabelControl` which will have a `*` by default after it's text. This would help me in decreasing the number of labels in my form. The custom label is actually a combination of two things - First a text for the label, secondly the `*` in red color. I searched for this a lot, but can't find anything to start with. Please help with some suggestions.

Comment: You can solve this using CSS. Apply some specific class for the labels which are mandatory and then show the * using CSS class.

Comment: Clearly nobody can tell that you are asking a winforms question.  You fix that by using the [winforms] tag.  And no, replacing one label with one usercontrol doesn't get you ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options - a custom label control or a user control that contains the label and the * based on a Mandatory property. If you have an explicit need to make the "*" red (seems to be the case per your q), you will need to use the user control. This is slightly heavier, so I would recommend rethinking that requirement. Here's how the custom label control would look:

```
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public CustomLabel()
    {

    }

    public bool Mandatory { get; set; }

    public override String Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text + " *";
        }
    }    
}
```

You would now use the CustomLabel instead of the Label.

Comment: Ok. What would be the approach for a red * ?

Comment: @Sandeep I would not change the `Text` property, rather override the `OnPaint` event to add the red * after painting the base test.

Comment: @Sandeep, you can use a User Control composed of two labels. Hide the label holding "*" when Mandatory is set to False. The only issue here is you will need to expose the Text property etc. for others to consume it as if it were a label.

Comment: @Rotem's approach will also work. It will probably be more efficient too. Overriding the Text property's getter has a disadvantage if your code relies on the label's Text property for some reason. Not a usual usage though. Otherwise, it's quite safe to use.